# AngularJS - Getting filtered ng-repeat $index from inside a controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have an `ng-repeat` list with a filter.  I can't seem to find how to get the visible `$index` from inside of my controller.

I can easily display it and it changes dynamically when the list is getting filtered.

```
<div ng-repeat="stuff in myList| filter:query | orderBy:orderProperty">
    <label>{{$index}}</label>
</div>
```

But I can't seem to get the correct `$index` programatically from within my controller.  I've tried `$scope.myList.indexOf(myObj`) and a for loop, but I still don't get the right $index, I get the `$index` of the item in the original, unfiltered, list.

The reason I need this is because I have a global audio player and I need to autoplay the filtered list.  So when my audio 'ended' I fire off to play the `next()` element in the visible list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to solve this issue is to write your own custom filter and before returning the array, add an index to every element then use that index instead of $index.

Here is some sample code.

```
angular.module('myFilters', []).filter('filterWithIndex', function() {
  return function(input) {
    var filteredInput = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < input.length; i ++) {
      filteredInput.push(input[i]);
      filteredInput[i].index = i + 1;
    }

    return filteredInput;
  };
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind doing all of the filtering and ordering in code, you can do everything inside your controller. Just make sure you inject `$filter` to it first.

```
// $filter must be injected earlier
$scope.filteredList = function(list) {
    var result;
    result = $filter('filter')(list, $scope.query);
    result = $filter('orderBy')(result, $scope.orderProperty);
    return result;
};
```

Then your HTML becomes

```
<div ng-repeat="stuff in filteredList(myList)">
    <label>{{$index}}</label> 
</div>
```